# Multiple buckets authentication with Admin user

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I have multiple buckets and on my existing config I have a user for each bucket where the username is the name of the bucket and the password is a single password for all the buckets.. this is functioning as a work-around for rbac that was released with 5.x and the removal of bucket-level passwords.

Now I've spent many hours today figuring out how I can control all the buckets with a single admin user (in order for me to finally get rid of the many un-neccessary users)
[image: New admin user]

I'm running latest `couchbase 5.5.2` and `spring-data-couchbase 3.1.1.RELEASE` which should have the rbac support as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/commit/0960f11a9ccd5263add07f6c1b2a526e87706baa)

The documentation doesn't mention how I can achieve this and the comments in the github link above are vague and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

You'll need to overwrite following method from `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration`, specifying the rbac user

```
@Override
protected String getUsername() {
    return "Admin";
}
```

Then change all your bucket beans to use `openBucket(String s1)` instead of `openBucket(String s1, String s2)`

```
@Bean
public Bucket kBucket() throws Exception {
    return couchbaseCluster().openBucket("buck");
}
```